# Zebra Browser Print to Networked Printer ~HQES receives blank response

Tags: printing, zebra-printers

I am using Browser Print in a web application on Windows to an iMZ320 printer.   When the printer is connected via USB the whole flow of the application works fine, the ~HQES request for printer status returns information and I can send commands and items to print successfully.

When I change the printer connection to a network connection I can print fine using Browser Print but the ~HQES response is empty.   I can take the HTTP POST  command to print and send it via Postman and it works fine.  When I send the ~HQES command in Postman I get an empty response with a 200 (success) response, so it's not that it's the Browser Print code masking the response in some way.  When I use the Zebra Setup Utilities to send the ~HQES command I get the response :

```
"







  PRINTER STATUS                           

  ERRORS:         0 00000000 00000000     

  WARNINGS:       0 00000000 00000000     

"
```

When I send the command via the Zebra Setup Utilities when the printer is out of printer or the door is open I get the expected error response in the same format the the OK response shown above.

Does anybody know how I can get hold of the printer status information for the networked printer?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example in vb.

Private Function ZPLTest(Ip As String) As String

```vb
    Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient()
    ZPLTest = "0-Printer on line"
    'check if ip is active
    Try
        client.Connect(Ip, 9100)
    Catch se As SocketException
        ZPLTest = "1-Printer off or network down"
        Exit Function
    End Try

    'send command
    Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(client.ReceiveBufferSize - 1) {}
    Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(stream)
    sw.Write("~HQES")
    sw.Flush()

    'check if stream reader is ok
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While stream.DataAvailable = False
        Thread.Sleep(10)
        i += 1

        If i = 30 Then
            ZPLTest = "1- Printer not send status"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End While


    'read status printer
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
    Dim length As Integer = 0
    Thread.Sleep(500)
    While (stream.DataAvailable)
        length += stream.Read(buffer, length, (buffer.Length - length))
    End While

    sr.Close()
    sw.Close()
    client.Close()

    Dim results As String = (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length))

    Dim Errore As String = results.Substring(36, 1)

    If Errore = "1" Then ZPLTest = "1-Generic error"

    Dim Media As Integer
    Try
        Media = CInt(results.Substring(54, 1))
        If Media = 1 Then ZPLTest = "1-Error label"
        If Media > 1 Then ZPLTest = "1-Error ribbon"
        If Media > 3 Then ZPLTest = "1-Head open"
    Catch

    End Try

End Function
```